# Grouping questions in the theme of "how to roleplay a character more X than I am"

Tags: discussion

Are there any options for grouping together those questions? I've seen a number of them now, most of them attract really good answers. But they seem to be a common theme and I might imagine that many people who are looking for one of these might also be interested in others.

Is it possible to do something a Community Wiki post where we gather all of them together? Maybe add a new tag to all of them? Or is the site not supposed to work like that?

I can see the whole set of questions together to be an amazing resource for people who are trying to work on their roleplaying skills (whether as a player or DM).

For reference, here's some of the questions I'm talking about:

[How can I DM a character with more social skills than me?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56968/how-can-i-dm-a-character-with-more-social-skills-than-me)

[How do I roleplay a character more intelligent than I am?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-do-i-roleplay-a-character-more-intelligent-than-i-am?lq=1)

[How can I roleplay a character more manipulative than myself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36633/how-can-i-roleplay-a-character-more-manipulative-than-myself?lq=1)

[How do I GM a character immeasurably more intelligent than myself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53042/how-do-i-gm-a-character-immeasurably-more-intelligent-than-myself?lq=1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These all fall under our [roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roleplaying) tag. "How to roleplay X better" is a subset of roleplaying problems, so the tag fits. Do we need a more specific tag for this subset though? Not really: Since *most* possible questions about how to play a role are actually too subjective for the Stack, these questions are a significant proportion of those under the tag, so they're easy enough to find, when they're properly tagged.